# Installing Ubuntu 15.05 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, uefi, gpt, ubuntu-15.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1. Windows 8.1 is currently installed, the computer has two drives, both of which (as near as I can tell), use GPT. The first drive is an SSD, and I managed to resize it and add a partition for Ubuntu. The second is a disk drive.

I initially tried to install 14.04, but couldn't get it to boot, even after trying tools like [easyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and [easyuefi](http://www.easyuefi.com/) and [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html).

So after spending many hours on that, I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi). I switched from 14.04 to 15.04, ecstatic that all my woes would soon be forgotten.

Unfortunately, I cannot even install it as it hangs at the "Preparing to install Ubuntu" screen.

I am really at my wits end here. Why would it hang at that screen? What can I check to make this dual boot work?

Comment: Since you got further with 14.04 than with 15.04, and since 14.04 is a long-term support (LTS) version, I recommend you go back to 14.04 and tackle the boot problem. Note that `gdisk` will do little or nothing to help you boot. Depending on the nature of the problem, EasyBCD and EasyUEFI may not help, either. Read [my page on EFI-mode Linux installs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) and, if that doesn't help, post a new question providing details of what's not working, including [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get 15.04 to stop hanging, so I switched back to 14.04.

I managed to make 14.04 work when I saw an "Advanced Boot" option under the boot option during the initial UEFI options menu on boot (like the BIOS menu, you just hold down a key like `delete` or whatever your computer uses to open the menu on boot). In the `Advanced Boot` options, it turns out I could choose the bootloader installed on the ubuntu partition. That bootloader correctly showed ubuntu alongside the windows loader, so I have the option to boot into either.

I'm still not entire sure I understand UEFI and it's various idiosyncrasies, but for anyone having a similar problem, I suggest looking for an Advanced Boot option or something similar in the UEFI options menu.